# SQL Query - Need to get a value not in a table

Tags: php, sql

I have the following **SQL** for my **PHP** project, I need to receive the *Module Status* Text to match the status Id in the *Module* Table, but if the status id value doesn't exist, can I set a value in the SQL?
This is a simple Query but Im looking for an efficient solution so I dont have to run 2 seperate queries.

Thanks in advance..

Below is what I have now but it does select the values that are not reference in ModuleStatus.

```
SELECT m.moduleID, m.moduleDesc,s.statusDesc,
FROM Modules m, ModuleStatus s 
WHERE s.statusID = m.statusID
```

Below is a simplified version of the results Im getting...

**Module**

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|   ID   |   Desc  |  Stat   |
+--------+---------+---------+
|   5    |   Car   |  1      |
+--------+---------+---------+
|   6    |   Bike  |  2      |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

**ModuleStatus**

```
+--------+---------+
|   ID   |   Desc  |
+--------+---------+
|   1    | on      |
+--------+---------+
|   0    | off     |
+--------+---------+
```

The results would be 

**Result**

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|   ID   |   Desc  |  Stat   |
+--------+---------+---------+
|   5    |   Car   |  on     |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

But What I want is

**Expect!!**

```
+--------+---------+---------+
|   ID   |   Desc  |  Stat   |
+--------+---------+---------+
|   5    |   Car   |  on     |
+--------+---------+---------+
|   6    |   Bike  | Unknown |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: hey thank you everyone for your contributions, It looks like I have found the solution for me, but as a newbie here do I set the answer Iiked somewhere, I tried to vote on some responses but apparently not allowed!! Anyway, thankyou ALL!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a left outer join :

```
SELECT m.moduleID, m.moduleDesc,s.statusDesc,
FROM Modules m
LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleStatus s 
ON s.statusID = m.statusID
```

Good examples in this answer -> [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

As suggested by @MGA ... you could change the missing values to "unknown" by updating the select statement :

```
SELECT m.moduleID, m.moduleDesc, IsNull(s.statusDesc,'Unknown')
FROM Modules m
LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleStatus s 
ON s.statusID = m.statusID
```

Comment: +1,Perfect.BTW: I think it should be `IsNull(s.statusDesc,'Unkown')`

Comment: @MGA - OK - rather than `null` ... i will update the answer ... thanks

Comment: I like the the second solution provided but its not executing. Im running it through php mysql_query() so I prob have a SPACE or comma in the wrong place!

Comment: @IEnumerable - yep my fault - comma on the end of the select ... updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.moduleID, m.moduleDesc,s.statusDesc,
FROM Modules m left outer join ModuleStatus s 
on s.statusID = m.statusID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.moduleID AS ID, m.moduleDesc AS Desc, 
       ISNULL(s.statusDesc, 'Unknown') AS Stat
FROM Modules m
LEFT OUTER JOIN ModuleStatus s 
ON s.statusID = m.statusID
```

Comment: thanksyou this one worked best for me, I looked up left outer join but the resuts are multiple records that does not suit me. Thankyou